# Specify path to node_modules in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to move the node_modules directory in an application to let's say /vendor/node_modules like bower does with the bowerrc file? I thought it could be specified in package.json but I can't seem to find a solution. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess something similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974436/change-node-modules-location](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18974436/816213)

Comment: I'm not sure why you've accepted an answer that clearly doesn't answer your question. You ask how to set the path to `node_modules` *in `package.json`*, and xShirase's answer simply doesn't provide a way to do that.

Comment: He probably accepted the answer because this is very clearly an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and an alternative solution is better than "sorry, that's not possible."

Comment: In webpack.config there is an option which could do the trick.
Webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules 
Here "node_modules" is set by default but you can remove it and search modules in another place. 
To test it I created a copy of the node_modules after install: (in package.json)
"postinstall": "cp -r ./node_modules ./juan_node_modules",
And in webpack.config.js i added this:
 resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'juan_node_modules')],
...
It seems to work.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

yes you can, just set the NODE_PATH env variable :

```
export NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules
```

According to the doc :

> If the NODE_PATH environment variable is set to a colon-delimited list
>   of absolute paths, then node will search those paths for modules if
>   they are not found elsewhere. (Note: On Windows, NODE_PATH is
>   delimited by semicolons instead of colons.)
>
> Additionally, node will search in the following locations:
>
> 1: $HOME/.node_modules
>
> 2: $HOME/.node_libraries
>
> 3: $PREFIX/lib/node
>
> Where $HOME is the user's home directory, and $PREFIX is node's
>   configured node_prefix.
>
> These are mostly for historic reasons. **You are highly encouraged to
>   place your dependencies locally in node_modules folders.** They will be
>   loaded faster, and more reliably.

[Source](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

Comment: That is great. So in my case where I have local node_modules to each application I'm building, would I do that export in a js file in the project?

Comment: nope, it's an environment variable, it's setup at system-level. So you have to type it in your terminal. env variables are accessed within a node app in `process.env`

Comment: i try to run that in Windows and it doesnt work, it says: `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`, it worked for me in OS X.

Comment: I don't really think this is the answer to the question: He was asking for a property within the package.json to put a path for LOCAL (application level) npm-Packages. This answer tells him how he can move the GLOBALLY (-g) installed packages into another folder.

Comment: There is no word "property" in question or its title. Author write `I thought it could` be in package.json. But you can specify env variable in `package.json` at script run command like this: `{"scripts": { "start": "NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules node ./your-app.js"}}` You also can use all expand ability of your shell.

Comment: "node will search those paths for modules if they are not found elsewhere" --- so, lowest priority in the search order.

Answer (score 36):

In short: It is not possible, and as it seems won't ever be supported (see here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775).

There are some hacky work-arrounds with using the CLI or ENV-Variables (see the current selected answer), .npmrc-Config-Files or `npm link` - what they all have in common: They are never just project-specific, but always some kind of `global` Solutions.

For me, none of those solutions are really clean because contributors to your project always need to create some special configuration or have some special knowledge - they can't just `npm install` and it works.

So: Either you will have to put your package.json in the same directory where you want your node_modules installed, or live with the fact that they will always be in the root-dir of your project.

Comment: "If you want to spell "node_modules" differently, sorry, no can do. That's built into node-core. Changing that is tantamount to building a completely different package manager." <== good job using variables I guess.

Comment: A comment from 2019: it looks like yarn supports overriding the modules directory. Well, yarn is a new package manager, I suppose.

Answer (score 21):

Yarn supports this feature:

```
# .yarnrc file in project root
--modules-folder /node_modules
```

But your experience can vary depending on which packages you use. I'm not sure you'd want to go into that rabbit hole.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind, but I ended up on this question because I was unable to install `node_modules` inside my project dir as it was mounted on a filesystem that did not support symlinks (a VM "shared" folder).

I found the following workaround:

1. Copy the `package.json` file to a temp folder on a different filesystem
2. Run `npm install` there
3. Copy the resulting `node_modules` directory back into the project dir, using `cp -r --dereference` to expand symlinks into copies.

I hope this helps someone else who ends up on this question when looking for a way to move `node_modules` to a different filesystem.

#### Other options

There is another workaround, which [I found on the github issue that @Charminbear linked to](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775#issuecomment-50301534), but this doesn't work with `grunt` because it does not support `NODE_PATH` as per https://github.com/browserify/resolve/issues/136:

> lets say you have `/media/sf_shared` and you can't install symlinks in
>   there, which means you can't actually npm install from
>   `/media/sf_shared/myproject` because some modules use symlinks.
>
> - `$ mkdir /home/dan/myproject && cd /home/dan/myproject`
> - `$ ln -s /media/sf_shared/myproject/package.json` (you can symlink in this
>     direction, just can't create one inside of /media/sf_shared)
> - `$ npm install`
> - `$ cd /media/sf_shared/myproject`
> - `$ NODE_PATH=/home/dan/myproject/node_modules node index.js`

Answer (score 0):

What if I am inside docker and I want to persist the `node_modules` in a volume? Then, having the `node_modules` inside of my app path is not an option for me.

When I deploy new code into the container, I put a tar into it, extract it to a temporary folder and then rsync from that to the app directory. I have the `--delete` flag set for rsync, so everything that's not in the tar is removed from the app folder. That also applies to the `node_modules` folder, so unfortunately the only solution that worked for me is the following:

> Create a symbolic link in the app directory to a directory that contains the `node_modules` and is mounted into the container from the host.