# NodeJS: how to use package.json and node_modules in different directories

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have an app using the file structure

```
package.json
src/main/
 - webapp
 - java (containing my API)
```

My API is restricted so that it can only dispatch files from within `src/main/webapp`, as a result I need my `node_modules` to install within that folder.

If I run `npm install` I get the following:

```
package.json
node_modules/
src/main/
 - webapp
 - java (containing my API)
```

Is there a way I can change this so it installs by default in the following structure?

```
package.json
src/main/
 - webapp
    - node_modules/
 - java (containing my API)
```

If possible I'd rather not have a global environment variable as I work on multiple apps on this machine and I don't want them all installing to this apps `node_modules`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify path to node\_modules in package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742553/npm-local-install-package-to-custom-location

Comment: Why do you care where the dependencies are? As long as the runtime finds and loads them, you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Amit My server needs to be able to dispatch them which is only possible from within src/main/webapp

Comment: @Amit for example if I was to have a dependency on Angular (which I would need in my index.html dependencies) then that would need to be dispatchable by my server, hence it would need to be in src/main/webapp

Comment: By "*dispatch*" do you mean *serve* (as in "web server")?

Comment: @Amit I do indeed :)

Comment: @JoshC. Using an environment variable like those answers suggest would surely mean by other apps would pick it up as well wouldnt it? I would like all my apps to be self contained if possible

Comment: And you're using paths that include "/node_modules/angular/..." to do that? That's not the way you should do things

Comment: @Amit what alternative is there? This is what https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular seems to be suggesting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101924/discussion-between-amit-and-ed0906).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case above I intended to install my webapp dependencies, such as AngularJS using NodeJS. It turns out there is another package manager [Bower](http://bower.io/) that is much more fit for this purpose and allows you to configure the location of its `bower_components`to wherever you like. This has solved my issue and I now have the following file structure

```
package.json
node_modules/
src/main/
 - webapp
    -bower_components
        -angular (etc) 
 - java (containing my API)
```