# i want to create node_modules folder outside my server side folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i have created server side folder inside which i have node_modules and package.json.what i want to do is move the node_modules folder outside the server folder.My folder structure is given below:
server
    node_modules
    controller
    package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set path for npm_packages.

please find below example - its done on linux, similarly, you might have to do things on your platform

```
mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
nano $HOME/.bashrc
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"
PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
unset MANPATH
MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
#Save and exit
nano $HOME/.npmrc
prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages
#Save and exit
source ~/.bashrc
```

UPDATE: i haven't used windows for quite sometime, but what you should do is -> set `NPM_PACKAGES` in your `$PATH(env  etc)`  also add `NPM_PACKAGES` onto `NODE_PATH`.   next you edit `.npmrc`   and add a prefix in here, something like `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages`

also please follow these links

[Specify path to node_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)

[How to change node_modules path in windows](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9840)

Comment: @suresh : if it works, then you accept/up vote the answer, thats how thanks works in SO