# How can I reference node_modules components inside Symfony's Views

Tags: npm, symfony

I have installed a widget using `npm`. It is installed under `node_modules` folder. I need to include the widget's javascript and CSS files in my `View` but since they are not in `Web` folder I can't include them, using the following method :

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/someFolder/.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How can I achieve the above?

Comment: The documentation suggests you use other tools like grunt and bower to build and deploy your web assets [web-assets frontend-based-applications](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html#frontend-based-applications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as explained here [Specify path to node_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json) there is no proper way to instruct `package.json` to put the dependencies in some specific path. I had to manually change to the `Web` folder and then download the widget's dependencies there.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways around this issue that I know of. I'm going to show you the way I use node_modules in symfony. I use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) and [Assetic bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html) for this, it's actually easier than you think.

1. Install yarn for your system and install assetic bundle in symfony. They are pretty straightforward.
2. Create a new directory inside your AppBundle (or in any of your bundles) and name it Assets. Go to  your assets directory from console and install your node modules there using Yarn.

   `yarn add bootstrap@3.3.7`
3. Now you can include your asset as follows in your view.

   `{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Assets/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
   {% endstylesheets %}`

Hope this helps.