# How to specify a path to node_modules in Typescript solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a Typescript solution in Visual Studio 2015 based on [this guide](http://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-2-getting-started-with-a-visual-studio-2015-typescript-project/).

I want to keep `node_modules` outside of the solution/project.

The post "[Specify path to node_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)" explains how to do so in `node.js` environment, but I cannot find a way to apply it in Visual Studio.

Note: I don't really care about `package.json`, `node_modules` and other `Node.js` stuff in my Visual Studio solution since I have another repository with third-party libraries (where I'm planning to dump `node_modules` there).

So, the question is how to specify a path to `node_modules` (located outside of the VS solution)?