# How to configure node_modules folder location in npm project?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a `node` application in which I am using `package.json` file which on npm install make a `node_modules` folder inside the `application` folder which have all dependencies in it. I  want to move `node_modules` folder out from `application` folder without causing the code break. Basically I want to manually configure the location of local node modules. How can I do that?

Comment: You can move package.json to this other folder and run npm install there.

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf but then i am unable to use those node modules inside my code.

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can change main to whatever the location is relative to package.json and then it can work with node _modules as expected. Maybe check other answer on StackOverFlow since I saw similar questions to yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify path to node\_modules in package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)