# Require node_modules from a relative path in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, node-modules

All works fine when I have the `node_modules` folder in the sameone as the `gulpfile.js`.

But whenever I place `node_modules` anywhere outside it, I can't seem to make it work by using relative paths:

```
var gulp = require('../../node_modules/gulp');
var rename = require('../../node_modules/gulp-rename');
```

I get the following message:

```
[20:11:45] Task 'default' is not in your gulpfile
[20:11:45] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

But I in fact have a `default` task and it runs as expected when not using relative paths.

I also tried including them without specifiying the node_modules folder, as I though it should be:

```
var gulp = require('../../gulp');
var rename = require('../../gulp-rename');
```

But I get the following error:

> module.js:538
>      throw err;
>      ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '../../gulp'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `require` without a path, like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
```

This triggers `require` to search for the `node_modules` folder, automatically checking each parent folder up to the root. https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: Uh! Ah! Oh!! Wonder why I didn't try that first! Thanks! Working fine now!