# Can not start composer-cli

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I followed the [instructions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html) to install the hyperledger tools on Ubuntu 18.04. Due to a permission problem I had to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json) the node_modules directory.

I can run the tools, except composer-cli (composer-cli: command not found).

Installation log:

```
$ npm install -g composer-cli@0.20
...

WARN engine fabric-client@1.2.1: wanted: {"node":"^8.9.0","npm":"^5.5.1"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
    /home/asset-tracker/.npm-global/bin/composer -> /home/asset-tracker/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js
    /home/asset-tracker/.npm-global/lib
    └── composer-cli@0.20.4 

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /composer-cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
```

Comment: composer-cli is the npm package name, not the command name.  Try `composer -v` which should print out the composer version.

Comment: thx, it‘s working now, v0.20.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as seen in the log snippet. I think you should try to upgrade the version of npm.

hyperledger-composer supports Ubuntu Linux 14.04 / 16.04 LTS (both 64-bit). Installing to 18.04 might facing unexpected error. [installing prereqs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html#ubuntu)

Comment: thx for reminding me of the wrong OS version. The npm version is 6.4.1, not sure if I upgraded npm meanwhile, though.