# Set global search directory for node.js process

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to set a global search directory for entire node.js process, so all calls to `require('module')` (in any file) will try to load the requested module from the specified directory first?

I don't want to change the path to a `node_modules` directory or to rename it. I want to add another search location for node resolution algorithm, which will be looked up prior the `node_modules`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify path to node\_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)

Comment: @JakeHolzinger this is not a duplicate. I've updated the question to specifically explain this.