# How to separate package.json from node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

It's possible to store package.json in main directory of app and set path to /node_modules directory in other place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify path to node\_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)

Answer (score 0):

set the NODE_PATH env variable :

```
export NODE_PATH='your_dir'/node_modules
```

*It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably.*