# Typescript in Docker: "Cannot find module" in Visual Studio code host typescript compiler

Tags: typescript, docker, visual-studio-code

**Project setup**

I have a Typescript project I'm running in a local Docker container. I have the following two volumes (this is in `docker-compose.yml`):

```
volumes:
  - .:/node/app
```

This first volume is a bind mount, to copy in my app's source code into the container.

```
  - /node/app/node_modules/
```

This second volume is **inside** the bind mount. This means that when an `npm install` runs inside the container, in the project's `/node/app` working directory, the dependencies will be installed into the `node_modules` folder **in the container only.**

My understanding is this is a common practice to allow the host and the container to have separate `node_modules`. My intention for this setup is to install and run some tools in the host only, like **prettier**, so I can `npm install --only=development` in the host, and get prettier installed, as its specified as a devDependency, and now my editor can use prettier.

**The problem**

In my editor, when the typescript compiler runs, it shows me "Cannot find module" errors:

[image: cannot find module errors in visual studio code]

My understanding is this happens because those modules aren't on disk. This is because of my above setup. I have made the `node_modules` containing my **non-dev dependencies**, like React, only available inside the container.

**My question**

I'm new to Docker, and my understanding is it's generally good to do things inside the container, including development. I'm trying to avoid an `npm install` in the host, because I don't really want or need all of the dependencies in the host. I also don't want to have to `npm install` twice, once on host and once in container, when adding a new dependency.

Is there a way to stop Typescript from erroring if the node_modules imported aren't present (like only load their typing definitions, maye?), **or** is there a way to point Typescript's compiler in Visual Studio Code somehow to the container, so it can see them without having to install them on the host, while still letting me install other dependencies on the host, like prettier?

Or is the only way to `npm install` on the host?

Comment: I ran into the same scenario and one option I found is to use the Remote - Containers extension if you use VSCode. It lets you plug into the container and work directly there. [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers)

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a separate volume for `node_modules` would be common if you wanted to install modules both inside and outside docker. For example, if you wanted to run your project outside of docker containers, and be able to run it in the docker containers.

What you are suggesting, having some modules inside the container and others outside, I'm not sure there's any need for that. Perhaps the better solution would be to just run `prettier` inside your docker container...

```
services:
    prettier:
        image: node:latest
        volumes:
            - .:/node/app
        working_dir: /node/app
        entrypoint: npx prettier
```

Then you can run

```
docker-compose run --rm prettier <options>
```

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of this kind of "seperation". Have you some sources for me, that explain why this is "good" (as comment)?

And my answer: You can change the path of `node_modules`-directory. Have a look to [Specify path to node_modules in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json)

So you can define a mount-point in docker to a local folder. Read this [How-to](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container).
And this folder, you can define in npm. Maybe you have to change the running user of your docker-container, so the file-permissions will match with your host.

### But ...

I highly recommend to use npm like as it is supposed to use. Install it on your host-machine and use the project-local `node_modules`-folder. It will be much easier as the docker-volume-hack.

Comment: didn't helped much but thanks for activity on this question