# How to avoid node_modules folder being deleted

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to create a Docker container to act as a test environment for my application. I am using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine
WORKDIR /test
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install .
CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple. I only want to install all dependencies but NOT copy the code, because I will run that container with the following command:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/test -t <image-name>
```

But the problem is that `node_modules` directory is deleted when I mount the volume with `-v`. Any workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind mount test directory with $PWD, you container test directory will be overridden/mounted with $PWD. So you will not get your node_modules in test directory anymore.
To fix this issue you can use two options.

1. You can run `npm install` in separate directory like /node and mount your code in test directory and export [node_path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293049/specify-path-to-node-modules-in-package-json) env like `export NODE_PATH=/node/node_modules`
   then Dockerfile will be like:

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine
WORKDIR /node
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install .
WORKDIR /test
CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

2. Or you can write a entrypoint.sh script that will copy the node_modules folder to the test directory at the container runtime.

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine
WORKDIR /node
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install .
WORKDIR /test
COPY Entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["Entrypoint.sh"]
```

and Entrypoint.sh is something like

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r /node/node_modules /test/.
npm test
```

Answer (score 0):

***Approach 1***

A workaround is you can do

`CMD npm install && npm run dev`

***Approach 2***

Have docker install `node_modules` on `docker-compose` build and run the app on `docker-compose up`.

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services: 
  api:
    container_name: /$CONTAINER_FOLDER    
    build: ./$LOCAL_FOLDER
    hostname: api
    volumes:
      # map local to remote folder, exclude node_modules
      - ./$LOCAL_FOLDER:/$CONTAINER_FOLDER
      - /$CONTAINER_FOLDER/node_modules
    expose:
      - 88
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /test
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install 

# run command
CMD npm run dev
```