# Using a shared npm node_modules/ for multiple workspaces on the same server

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

Our Jenkins/CI server runs hundreds of builds a day for our node/js project, and I would like to be able to run each build in a completely clean workspace. However, the `npm install` step can take >10 minutes, which is just far too slow. Instead, as our npm dependencies only change for a small number of builds (approx 1% of all builds), I'd like to only run `npm install` once every time `npm-shrinkwrap.json` changes (check md5sum at every build). If the shrinkwrap file hasn't changed, use a cached `node_modules/` directory.

This plan works well enough if I copy the cached `node_modules/`, however even that operation can take up to a minute. To further optimize our build times, I would like to be able to symlink to the cached `node_modules/`, which should drastically improve our overall build performance.

```
ln -s /path/to/cache/ /path/to/workspace/node_modules
```

However, simply symlinking to the path of the cache doesn't work in a case where a dependency exists at multiple levels of the dependency tree. As an example, our top level project depends on both `gulp` and `gulp-util`. The top level dependency also depends on `gulp-util`. After an `npm install`, `gulp-util` will be install in the top level `node_modules/` but not in `node_modules/gulp/node_modules`.

If the dependencies exist in the local workspace (i.e. a real directory `/path/to/workspace/node_modules/`), then any instance of `require('gulp-util')` within `node_modules/gulp` will (I think) recurse up the dependency tree until it finds an appropriate `gulp-util` module. That is, it starts off looking in `/path/to/workspace/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util`, doesn't find anything, then looks in `/path/to/workspace/node_modules/gulp-util`, finds an appropriate module, imports it and moves on.

However, when this is a symlink I'll get an error like:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/cache/gulp/index.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

I assume that this tries to do the same as the other version, but I can't see why it fails to find `gulp-util`. Whether it looks in `/path/to/workspace/node_modules/gulp-util` or `/path/to/cache/gulp-util`, it should find the module and be able to import it.

I've tried resolving this by manually installing the module `gulp/node_modules/gulp-util`, but I encounter dozens of such errors and dealing with this manually on a build server is unfeasible. Writing some code to search for dependencies of this type and installing them is possible, but it feels like the wrong thing to do.

npm must have some way of supporting such a workflow, right? Am I missing something obvious? Have I glossed over something in the documentation?

Comment: It's possible you'd get this working by switching to NPM 3.x, which changes the node_modules structure from `node_modules/parent/node_modules/child` to just `node_modules/child`.

Comment: Huh, I tried it with the most recent version npm 3.x and I had the exact same problem.

Comment: @laffoyb check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18974546/1341008
in short, try putting all modules on your NODE_PATH

Comment: @darko, actually, reading the top answer in that thread has given me an idea. It looks back up the path for folders named node_modules. My cache is at `/path/to/cache/`, maybe it would work correctly if it was at `/path/to/cache/node_modules/`? I can't test that right now, but I'll check it in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to an answer posted by @amol-m-kulkarni [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18974546/1341008) (helpfully referenced by @darko-rodic above), I realised my mistake.

> If the given module is not a core modules(e.g. http, fs, etc.),
>   Node.js will then begin to search for a directory named, node_modules.
>
> It will start in the current directory (relative to the
>   currently-executing file in Node.JS) and then work its way up the
>   folder hierarchy, checking each level for a node_modules folder. Once
>   Node.JS finds the node_modules folder, it will then attempt to load
>   the given module either as a (.js) JavaScript file or as a named
>   sub-directory; if it finds the named sub-directory, it will then
>   attempt to load the file in various ways. So, for example

My mistake was in the name I gave the cache path. As it was named `/path/to/cache`, `require` stopped looking upwards after the last `node_modules` dir it encountered in the path. In this case, it stopped at `/path/to/cache/gulp/node_modules`, and didn't realise that `/path/to/cache/gulp-util` should have been considered in the search.

I fixed this by renaming the cache to `/path/to/cache/node_modules` so `require` will continue searching until it reaches that level, and will subsequently find `/path/to/cache/node_modules/gulp-util`.

I'm going to refer to the docs again to see if this should have been clear to me or not.

Comment: I have the same problem. After I created node_modules folder under cache folder, it works. Thanks a lot!!!