# How does npm scripts prioritise local dependency over global ones?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I understand npm scripts adds `./node_modules/.bin` to your `PATH`, therefore you can simply run `npm test` using the `package.json` below, and npm will automagically use the local version of mocha found in `./node_modules/.bin`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
}
```

This is a nice feature, because it saves me writing `package.json` files like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha"
}
```

BUT what if I bring on a new developer who has mocha installed globally? or I need to push this to an environment with preconfigured global packages? If I am using the short-hand `mocha`, rather than `./node_modules/.bin/mocha` in my `package.json`, What takes precedence, the global or local package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Node.js will try to run first [your locally installed packages](http://2ality.com/2016/01/locally-installed-npm-executables.html#running-executables-from-a-nearby-node-modules).

> If you require a module, Node.js looks for it by going through all node_modules/ directories in ancestor directories (`./node_modules/`, `../node_modules/`, `../../node_modules/`, etc.). The first appropriate module that is found is used.

For a more detailed explanation about how Node.js resolves required modules, [here is a nice breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18974546/2902821).

Comment: Ok that looks promising, so `../../../../node_modules/` will always be the first appropriate module before `/usr/local/bin` (global) is checked. Sweet! thanks.