# Change node_modules path specific to project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a project structure

```
|-app
   |-...
|-libs
|- package.json
|- index.html
```

I want the node_modules folder to be inside 'libs' folder. Like this-

```
|-app
   |-...
|-libs
   |-node_modules
       |-angular
       |-...
|- package.json
|- index.html
```

Is there any way to set configuration for this. so that next time I install any package, that will be dependency will directly go to that folder.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can work, but can a symbolic link suit your needs ?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974436/change-node-modules-location

Comment: If you CD into the libs folder when you do `npm install` it should install packages into that node_modules folder.  Only problem is, doing an `npm init` inside your root isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

just cd into the folder and run `npm init`. That will create package.json file. Then you can add packages which will be installed in node_modules inside that folder.

Comment: I think OP wants to change the node_modules folder without changing the path when requiring the modules.